# Command line arguments only work for first element of array

Tags: perl

I have my entire script running inside a foreach loop because I want everything to be done for each element in an array. My problem is if I pass an options through the command line, it only uses that option for the first element in the array and not the remaining. I can't place Getoptions outside the foreach loop because the variables are declared at some points in the script. How can I make an option work for each iteration of a foreach loop and not just the first.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my @array = ("health", "weight", "height");
foreach my $element (@array){
......

GetOptions ("yest=s" => \$yesterday_file,
             "tod=s" => \$today_file,
             "tom=s" => \$tomorrow_file) or die;

sub getFiles (
.....
return $files[0], $files[1], $files[2];
)            

SET_FILES: {
    my @files = getFiles();
    $yesterday_file //= files[0];
    $today_file //= $file[1];
    $tomorrow_file //= $file[2];
};

}
```

So each of the files are given a path in-code, but since I'm allowing the user to pass a custom file path through the command line, it is only being done for the first element of the array. For example, if I send a path for `$today_file`, it is replacing the path for the first element "health", but not for the next two. For the next two it uses the path assigned in the code.

Comment: Please show the code. It difficult give advice without more details

Comment: @HåkonHægland I've just updated the post. Please let me know if it's clear now.

Comment: *"...it is replacing the path for the first element "health".."* Where are you using `$element` in the for loop?

Comment: @HåkonHægland in the sub that gets the file path. part of the path names contain one of the elements.

Comment: It is not completely clear what you want to do...Do you want to reset the input to `GetOptions()`? Then just save `@ARGV` outside the `for` loop, and reset it before each call to `GetOptions()`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yes, that's what I would like to do. The way I have my code set up now, I am not using ARGV. I'm not sure how I would set ARGV here since the each of the three variables for files already have paths unless differently specified through the command line.

Comment: Try something like `@ARGV = @saved_argv` where you create `@saved_argv` before the `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you want to do, but to reset `@ARGV` before each call to `GetOptions()` you can do:

```
my @array = ("health", "weight", "height");
my @saved_argv = @ARGV;
foreach my $element (@array){
    ......
    @ARGV = @saved_argv;
    GetOptions ("yest=s" => \$yesterday_file,
             "tod=s" => \$today_file,
             "tom=s" => \$tomorrow_file) or die;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!!!

Comment: Alternatively, `GetOptionsFromArray([@ARGV], ...) or die;`. Then you don't need an extra variable. See https://perldoc.pl/Getopt::Long#Parsing-options-from-an-arbitrary-array.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `GetOptions()` inside the loop seems like a very strange design decision. Your command line won't change, so calling it multiple times is very wasteful.

I know you say you need to do it like that because your variables are defined at various points inside the loop, but can't you define them outside the loop as well?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my @array = ("health", "weight", "height");

my ($yesterday_file, $today_file, $tomorrow_file);

GetOptions ("yest=s" => \$yesterday_file,
            "tod=s" => \$today_file,
            "tom=s" => \$tomorrow_file) or die;

foreach my $element (@array) {
  ...;

  SET_FILES: {
    my @files = getFiles();
    $yesterday_file //= $files[0];
    $today_file     //= $files[1];
    $tomorrow_file  //= $files[2];
  };

  ...;
}
```

You also seem to have defined your `getFiles()` subroutine inside the loop. That's a bad idea too. You should move that definition to before the loop too.